# View state vs Hidden field in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can we take decision for viewstate and hidden field in ASP.NET.

In my case i am using page cross post back and by using public properties of first page i am accessing them in second aspx page.

After getting public variable in second aspx page i need to access those value in second page but as soon as i do postback in second page, i am not able to find those value.

Hence to solve this issue i have two solution either use viewstate  in second page or using hidden field in second page.

I am not able to decide which one should i use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The approach is quite the same. Only difference should be the size of stored info (viewstate is using [sometimes encrypted] base64 while hidden fields use plain text unless you encode them yourself), and viewstate allows you to make sure the data was not tampered with thanks to the default validation it has in place.

Comment: You're welcome. o.k.w. raised another valid point - data you store in a hidden field can be manipulated with client-side. ViewState is indeed being stored as a hidden field on the markup, but is virtually inaccessible from client-side code.

Answer (score 3):

**Difference between view state and a hidden field in asp.net**

http://royalarun.blogspot.in/2012/03/difference-between-view-state-and.html

Both are used to store the value during the postback in asp.net , but

**In View state** -  not able to change the value by Client side code i.e java script.
**Hidden field** - possible to change value by Client side code.

**In View state** - You can store more than one value like Datatable and Dataset
**Hidden field** - You can store more than one value in  hidden field,by serialized it.

View state data is encrypted and Hidden field is not encrypted

Answer (score 2):

If the data is small and you want to manipulate the value based on some client-side behaviour, hidden field will be useful.